# How to remove file from the dir with different permisison

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

Dir - `test - ls -ld`  shows

```
ls -ld test
drwxr-xr-x  2 joe stduser 4096 May 25 16:25 test
```

inside test dir :

```
-rw-r--r--  1 admin stduser 0 May 25 16:25 a.txt
```

How to remove a.txt with out using sudo ..

I just tried

```
 sudo -u admin rm test/a.txt
rm: cannot remove `test/a.txt': Permission denied
```

How to resolve this isse ?

Comment: Not a programming question... you're not on the sudo-ers list, and you don't have permission to that file.  End of story.

Comment: Should be perhaps asked at http://serverfault.com/ instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove something from a directory, you need write access to the directory. Therefore, in your case, user `joe` should be able to remove anything from `test` even if that belongs to `admin`.

EDIT:

With regular `rm`, you'll get a warning like: `remove write-protected file... ?` and you need to answer `y`. With `rm -f` you'll get rid of the warning.

But anyway, `admin` cannot remove that file.

Answer (score 2):

```
rm -f test/a.txt
```

Forceful is the name of the game

```
> ls -ld z z/z
drwxr-xr-x 2 joet dev 14 May 25 12:36 z/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root dev  0 May 25 12:36 z/z
> rm -f z/z
> ls -ld z z/z
ls: cannot access z/z: No such file or directory
drwxr-xr-x 2 joet dev 6 May 25 12:36 z/
```

Answer (score 0):

check the owner of the file, and check the group of the file. Now check if the account you have logged into is the owner's account, then you can delete them. Else see if you are within the owner's group and the group has `rw` permission, then delete them. Else log into `root` if you have the password and then remove it.

Else boot your system with a live CD/DVD, mount that disk, and delete it.